# Why can't $|x| = x$ be solved the conventional way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I warn the reader beforehand that, perhaps, this question is laughably simple; yet I need assistance answering it. It is taught in schools how one can solve equations containing absolute values. The method is simple: take for example $|5x| = 10$. This is true in 2 ways only: when $5x$ equals $10$, and when $5x$ equals $-10$. The logic of the reasoning is simple and straightforward, and it should seem that such simple logic must apply to exactly all other cases in which absolute values are to be resolved. Yet what about $|x| = x$? The equation is obviously true for whenever $x$ is positive (this can also be seen by the definition for absolute values). Then why exactly doesn't the method shown in school provide the sought-for answer? On the contrary, it provides an incorrect solution. For $|x| = x$, according to the method, is true when $x = x$ or when $x = –x$. This is obviously erroneous. I only want to know why exactly the error occurs? And if there is a general case to when equations containing absolute values shouldn't be resolved using such a method. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Hint: does your method work on $|5x|=-10$? Can you figure out the necessary condition for your method to make sense?

Comment: Maybe one way to view it: in order to have $|x| = y$, it's a *necessary* condition, but not a *sufficient* one, that $x = y$ or $x = -y$.  Therefore, you end up with some set of candidates but you must plug back in to see which candidates are actually solutions.  (On the other hand, a necessary *and* sufficient condition is: $y \ge 0 \land (x = y \lor x = -y)$.)

Comment: $|x| = x $ for positive $x$ and never for negative $x$.  It IS ALSO CORRECT WHEN $x = - x$ because $ - x = x $ if and only if $x = 0 $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you are not using the "conventional" method correctly.

To solve $|f(x)|=g(x)$, the "conventional method" is:

1. Solve $f(x)\geq 0$ *and* $f(x)=g(x)$; and
2. Solve $f(x)\leq 0$ *and* $-f(x)=g(x)$.

So your original problem should really be done by doing:

1. Find all solutions to $x\geq 0$ and $5x=10$;
2. Then find all solutions to $x\lt 0$ and $-5x=10$.

The first case leads to $x=2$, the second to $x=-2$.

For $|x|=x$, you want to:

1. Find all solutions to $x\geq 0$ and $x=x$;
2. Then find all solution sto $x\lt 0$ and $-x=x$.

The first consists of all $x\geq 0$; the second is empty. So the solution set is precisely $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Truly, this has been of much help! I don't know how I didn't figure this out by myself. Thank you!

Comment: @Camelot823 It was all a matter of knowing what the conventional method really is. Once you get a wrong idea about a thing like that, it's hard to figure it out. I've been in that situation myself, and I suspect many other experts here have too.

Answer (score 5):

There is not contradiction using the usual method by cases, indeed for

- $\boxed{x\ge 0}$ we have by definition $|x|:=x$ therefore

$$|x|=x \iff x=x$$

which is true for any $x\ge 0$, and for

- $\boxed{x< 0}$ we have by definition $|x|:=-x$ therefore

$$|x|=x \iff -x=x$$

which is false for any $x<0$.